# Get particular part(s) from String in C#

Tags: c#

I'm reading an email and performing a few operations.

In email it can't be in defined format as below,

**Email formats:**

> Hi Team,
>
> Please create 7025-45-365-14, 9851-98-524-12
>       5741-55-452-45
>
> Thanks

```
MailItem.Body = "Hi Team,\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nPlease create 7025-45-365-14, 9851-98-524-12\r\n\r\n5741-55-452-45.\r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\nThanks\r\n"
```

My goal is to exact only the string parts into a loop one by one as below,

1st loop > 7025-45-365-14

2nd loop > 9851-98-524-12

3rd loop > 5741-55-452-45

I tried various logic but I can't extract as I need. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract digits in that pattern (4-2-3-2)

```
foreach (var m in new Regex(@"\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2})\b").Matches(mail))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```